# Trying to write a regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I am new to regex and I am trying to write a regex in a bash script .
I am trying to match `line` with a regex which has to return the second word in the line .

```
regex = "commit\s+(.*)"
line = "commit 5456eee"
if [$line =~ $regex] 
then
 echo $2
else 
 echo "No match"
fi
```

When I run this I get the following error:-

```
man.sh: line 1: regex: command not found
man.sh: line 2: line: command not found
```

I am new to bash scripting . 
Can anyone please help me fix this .
I just want to write a regex to capture the word that follows `commit`

Comment: **Note:** the `=~` operator is only valid with double bracket syntax `[[ .. ]]`

Comment: Your seeing *command not found* because you have a space between the variable name and the value. Example: regex = "commit\s+(.*)" should become regex="commit\s+(.*)". See answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the spaces around the equals sign, otherwise bash thinks you want to execute the `regex` command using `=` and `"commit\s+(.*)"` as arguments.
Then you should remove the spaces also in the if condition and quote the strings:

```
$ regex="commit\s+(.*)"
$ line="commit 5456eee"
$ if [ "$line"=~"$regex" ]
> then
>   echo "Match"
> else 
>   echo "No match"
> fi
Match
```

Comment: There is no `=~` operator for `[ .. ]`, only `[[ .. ]]`

Comment: You can use `=~` like that as long you don't have spaces around the operator.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a `regex`, you want **parameter expansion/substring extraction**:

```
line="commit 5456eee"
first="${line% *}"
regex="${line#* }"
if [[ $line =~ $regex ]] 
    then
    echo $2
else 
    echo "No match"
fi
```

`$first == 'commit'`, `$regex == '5456eee'`. Bash provides all the tools you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you really only need the second word you could also do it with `awk`

```
line = "commit 5456eee"
echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

or if you have a file:

```
cat filename | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Even if it's no bash only solution, awk should be present on most linux os's.

Comment: How do i copy the output into a variable?

Comment: You could redirect it with another pipe, output it to a file using `cat filename | awk '{ print $2 }' > filename` or just do `output=$(cat filename | awk '{ print $2 }')` to capture output inside the $output var.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you didn't start your script with the

```
#!/bin/sh
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to define the language you're using... ?
It must be your first line.
then be careful, spaces are consistant in bash. In your "if" statement, it should be :

```
if [ $line =~ $regex ]
```

check this out and tell us more about the errors you get

Answer (score 0):

if you make this script to a file like test.sh

and execute like that :

```
test.sh commit aaa bbb ccc
   $0     $1    $2  $3  $4
```

you can get the arguments eassily by $0 $1...

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get the resulting capture group that was matched (if there is one) is to use `BASH_REMATCH`, which puts the match results into it's own array:

```
regex=$"commit (.*)"
line=$"commit 5456eee"
if [[ $line =~ $regex ]] 
then
 match=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
 echo $match
else 
 echo "No match"
fi
```

Since you have only one capture group it will be defined within the array as `BASH_REMATCH[1]`. In the above example I've assigned the variable `$match` to the result of `BASH_REMATCH[1]` which returns:

```
5456eee
```